# Center content in Bootstrap Col

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center a form in the center of the page, but everytime I center the col, the contents get pushed to the left side of that col. I want the form to be the full width of the col-md-6 and that col centered in the middle of the page.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">Your Name:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Your Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">Your Email:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">Your Company:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Company Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">Your Contact:</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="email" name="contactemail" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">Choose file(s):</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input name="files" type="file" id="files" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
             <h5></h5>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="sbmtBtn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/OiRABZIff0

Comment: If you want the content of the inner column to take up the full width of the six column parent column, then the inner columns should add up to 12, not six as they do now.

Comment: So maybe i misunderstood how to col grid worked.  Thanks!!  So there can be 12 cols, inside of every col?

Comment: Yup. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `col-md-offset-3` before  `col-md-2`.

[Have a look at the bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/OnzpX9RiTs)

Also not that `col` should be defined within rows and rows should be encapsulated within `container`, so I modified the html structure a bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change your

`<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">`

to

`<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-4">`

Answer (score -1):

I have edited. check out this help you. 
http://www.bootply.com/QnYcyyIh2V